# C++/CLI DLL has keypair but fails strong name validation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, c++-cli, strongname

I just created a C++/CLI DLL using VS 2010 SP1, and I want to sign the DLL with a strong name. 
So I created the file TestNet.snk in the VS 2010 command prompt

```
sn -k TestNet.snk
```

and then I configured the project by adding the Key File in Linker->Advanced->Key File.

[Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Project Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chzxQ.png)

The resulting DLL has the key pair in it, but when I try to verify the DLL with the following command:

```
sn -v TestNetDLL.dll
```

I get the following error:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

TestNetDLL.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly
```

If I try to sign again the DLL with the strong name, I get this error:

```
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Failed to install key pair -- Object already exists.
```

So the key pair is installed in the DLL but it is not strongly named, What I'm missing?, More Settings? or Do I need to add something to the code? :(

I don't know what I'm missing, please help!, thank you for your advise or any suggestion.

Comment: IIRC, signing C++/CLI assemblies was borken in VS2010, mt.exe screws it up when it embeds the manifest and alters the file hash.  Use delay signing.

Comment: There was also the borked strong naming, which required editing the `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.targets` file to replace `%(Link.DelaySign)` with `$(LinkDelaySign)`, and the same for `KeyFile`.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to solve the problem:

1. I ran this command to create the key-pair file

   sn -k TestNet.snk
2. I installed the key-pair in a key container

   sn -i TestNet.snk MyTestNetContainer
3. I configured the VS 2010 project to use the key container instead of the Key File and also selected Delay Signing:YES as advised by **Hans Passant**
4. I rebuilt the project and verified the DLL with sn.exe and the verification was successful "Is Valid"

   sn -v TestNetDLL.dll
   Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Strong Name Utility  Version 4.0.30319.1
   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Assembly 'TestNetDLL.dll' is valid

Thanks to Hans Passant for their advise.